# Need help finding the sum in ruby pry debugging?

Tags: debugging

Currently new to coding..

```
def plus_two(num)
num + 2
num
binding.pry  
end
```

trying to get the return the sum of the original number (3) plus 2. to come out to 5

Comment: 1. Format your code. There is nice editor here on SO.

Comment: 2. What your exact problem? What does not work? What do you get when you execute your code?

Comment: When I execute my code I don't get the sum of 5 to come out.

Comment: i added  puts (5) = sum... but that does not work @nikem

Answer (score 0):

Your function will need to return the value after it has done the calculation otherwise doing `puts` will not print anything to the screen (stdout).

**Example:**

```
def sum_two(n)
    return n+2
end

puts sum_two(3)
```

In the code above, you are saying do `puts` by using the value returned from the `sum_two(3)` function.

**Output:**

> 5

Not sure whether this is the appropriate channel to make book recommendation for new coder but I personally find those 'HeadFirst series' books pretty engaging and helpful for new programmers. If you have time check out 'Head first ruby'.